# Dependent is the difference between two Likert scales: Which regression to use?

Tags: regression, multinomial-distribution, likert, ordered-logit

I asked participants in an experiment the same question once before and once after the experiment, to see the effect of the experiment on the answer. The answers were given on a 5-point scale. To me the change, so the difference between the before and the after answer to the question, is interesting. So I want to see which of multiple factors in the experiment caused the difference and accordingly want to run a regression on the DIFFERENCE in answers.

The difference is always an integer, ranging from -4 to 4. Since its not continuos, I'd like to use something like multinomial logit or ordered logit, but cannot decide which one would be exactly right. Is there a 'right' regression to use?

(Related, I have the problem that always a group of 5 participants took part in the same experiment. But I guess that can be solved with an FE or clusters.)

edit(clarification): I have 200 observations of 40 experimental groups with 5 participants each. Dependent variables in the above scenario would be changes in the experiment-setup (same in each group but different among groups), the relation of participants in a group (personal relation, class-difference, etc.) and socio-economics of participants

Comment: If you take differences, you treat the variables as being at least interval scaled. So, if the sample size is not too small, you could as well consider a linear (mixed effects) regression.

Answer (score 2):

I would run a bivariate ordinal model with the original responses, rather than their differences, constraining the demographic coefficients between the equations and letting the experimental condition coefficients to be free in the second response. In Stata, this can be done with `cmp`. You won't get much with 5 clusters, and that would be the limit to the # of explanatory variables if you cluster by them. If you have multiple observations per person, so that you have a few dozen data points, you can still do the random effects with `cmp` though.